# Can retrieve only 20 documents from a folder

Tags: docusignapi

I have a Spring CM folder that has 1000s of small files in it. I'm doing retrieval this way:

```
 GET /v201411/folders/{id}/documents
```

but when it executes, I get back only 20 files. The sum of all of their sizes is: `1.8 MB` and the Content Length of the response -> content -> headers is only `3.8 MB`.

I didn't find anything in their documentations that mentions the limit of retrieving documents via the api.

Is that really the limitation of spring CM?

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [API Collections](https://developers.docusign.com/clm-api/guides/object-api):

> Limit (integer): The maximum number of elements retrieved per request.
> Default limit is 20. Maximum limit is 100
>
> When there are more items in the collection than the specified limit,
> the application can page through the collection, retrieving the
> objects in chunks by specifying the limit and/or offset on the query
> string when the collection is requested. The first, previous, next,
> and last properties are added as a convenience by appending the
> appropriate limit and offset to the URI and a GET request can be done
> to this URIs specified by these properties to navigate the collection.

To minimize the number of sequential calls you need to make, you can adjust the limit property up to the max, 100.